# Unity-style WASD fly navigation in Maya?

Tags: navigation, unity-game-engine, mouse, maya

I am learning Autodesk Maya in school.

I already know Unity 3D.

I love the fact that in Unity you can hold down the right mouse button and then fly around with the WASD keys (like when you are in spectator mode in a shooting game).

Is this possible to do in Autodesk Maya? So far, I have only been able to find the standard rotate/zoom/pan controls in Maya.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Unity allows the first person navigation with WASD keys because it's a game engine, and there is some logic that permits it. Basically, using the FPS Controller, the engine applies a translation to the main character (and, consequently, to the main camera, that's attached to it).

Maya, instead, isn't a game engine, but a modeling software, and (AFAIK), it doesn't have built-in features to do that, because they are not essential to a software of that kind.

But, answering at your question, there exist plugins. There is [MayaFPS](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/plugin/mayafps--2), as an example. It permits to move the perspective camera around, and recreate a kind of exploration similar to FPSs' one.

Comment: This isn't actually very hard to do. All you do is you set a timed script job that goes on when mouse is pressed down and cancel the job when its released. Its just that a s and d are the most important hot keys in maya. Played around with this ten years ago.

Comment: Thanks, that plugin is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the newest version of Maya (Maya 2014 Service Pack 2 64 bit) :(